# How can I move into another folder to access other files in C#

Tags: c#, directory, filesystems, openxml

So here in my code, I am editing the word documents from a folder, and copied those files over to a temp folder and I was just wondering how I could access those files in the temp folder to pursue further actions. Here is my code:

```
 private static void editFieldsTest(string filename)
    {
        if (filename.StartsWith("q") | filename.Contains("cover"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nMoving question files to temp directory\n");

            var destinationFolder = @"temp\";

            var tmp_filename = $"{destinationFolder}{ Path.GetFileName(filename)}";

            try
            {
                File.Copy(filename, tmp_filename, true);

            }
            catch (IOException iox)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(iox.Message);
            }

            int fileLen = filename.Length;
                Console.WriteLine("editing question files...\n");
                string typeOfQuestion = filename.Substring(1, fileLen - 14);
                string timeGiven = filename.Substring(3, fileLen - 14);
                string marks = filename.Substring(5, fileLen - 14);
                string learningOutcome = filename.Substring(7, fileLen - 14);
                //string fifthIndex = filename.Substring(9, fileLen - 9);

                var valuesToFill = new Content(
                    new FieldContent("qnumber", typeOfQuestion),
                    new FieldContent("qmark", marks),
                    new FieldContent("qtime", timeGiven),
                    new FieldContent("learningOutcome", learningOutcome));

                using (var outputDocument = new TemplateProcessor(tmp_filename)
                    .SetRemoveContentControls(true))
                {
                    outputDocument.FillContent(valuesToFill);
                    outputDocument.SaveChanges();
                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the thing that you need is DirectoryInfo class, according to your code you can open needed directory like that

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(destinationFolder);
```

And then, I suppose, get files enumerable collection like that

```
var files = directory.EnumerateFiles();
```

Theres reference for further reading on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=net-5.0)

Also I can suggest few improvements to your code!

```
private static void editFieldsTest(string filename)
    {
        //By returning early you're reducing nesting and making your code more readable. 
        //Fail fast!
        if (!(filename.StartsWith("q") | filename.Contains("cover"))) 
            return;
        
        Console.WriteLine("\nMoving question files to temp directory\n");

        //Make things const and move them our from your method 
        //But only if you really think that they won't change
        //I suggest moving that const to method signature to improve extensibility
        const string destinationFolder = @"temp\";

        var tmpFilename = $"{destinationFolder}{ Path.GetFileName(filename)}";

        try
        {
            File.Copy(filename, tmpFilename, true);

        }
        catch (IOException iox)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(iox.Message);
        }

        //You can use var to redeem yourself from writing whole type every time
        var fileLen = filename.Length;
        Console.WriteLine("editing question files...\n");
        var typeOfQuestion = filename.Substring(1, fileLen - 14);
        var timeGiven = filename.Substring(3, fileLen - 14);
        var marks = filename.Substring(5, fileLen - 14);
        var learningOutcome = filename.Substring(7, fileLen - 14);
        //string fifthIndex = filename.Substring(9, fileLen - 9);

        var valuesToFill = new Content(
            new FieldContent("qnumber", typeOfQuestion),
            new FieldContent("qmark", marks),
            new FieldContent("qtime", timeGiven),
            new FieldContent("learningOutcome", learningOutcome));

        using (var outputDocument = new TemplateProcessor(tmpFilename)
            .SetRemoveContentControls(true))
        {
            outputDocument.FillContent(valuesToFill);
            outputDocument.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much for your feedback! I really appreciate it.